# Does the request get encrypted when posting to HTTPS from HTTP

Tags: ssl, https

If I have a form that posts to HTTPS from a page that is served on HTTP does the post request get encrypted? Is there a way to view the data submitted if someone is sniffing on the network?

I tried it with Fiddler and I was not able to view the data, but I'm wondering if there is more to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. But you might not want to host a user form on `http` that posts to `https` because the `http` can easily be changed by a "man in the middle" attack, leading to phishing and other security vulnerabilities. See here : http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/05/your-login-form-posts-to-https-but-you.html